# Rails3 Kaminari undefined with .all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

Hi
I wonder how to work around the problem I have with the pagination gem "Kaminari".

For what I've understood you cant paginate @user = User.all.page(5)?

But what if I have this code and want to paginate that, is it possible or do I need to change the code?

```
    @price   = Price.joins(:retailer, :retailer => :profile).
    where(['product_id=? AND size_id=?', params[:prod_id], params[:si_id]]).
    group(:retailer_id).order("SUM((prices.price * #{params[:amount].to_i}) + profiles.shippingCost)").all
```

The only thing I receive right now when applying.page(5) to that code is

```
undefined method `page' for #<Class:0x000001023c4558>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `.all` because the joins call, along with where and group, is returning an array of objects for you that meet your criteria. Remove your .all and call page on the instance variable (which you might want to rename to `@pages` or something else plural).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I changed the code to

    @prices   = Price.select("`prices`.*").joins(:retailer, :retailer => :profile).
        where(['product_id=? AND size_id=?', params[:prod_id], params[:si_id]]).
        group(:retailer_id).order("SUM((prices.price * #{params[:amount].to_i}) + profiles.shippingCost)").page(params[:page])

But now I receive this error

Comment: Column 'retailer_id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, retailer_id AS retailer_id FROM `prices` INNER JOIN `retailers` ON `retailers`.`id` = `prices`.`retailer_id` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`retailer_id` = `retailers`.`id` WHERE (product_id='1' AND size_id='3') GROUP BY retailer_id,retailer_id ORDER BY SUM((prices.price * 1) + profiles.shippingCost)

Comment: When using the <%= paginate @prices %> in the view

Comment: Hi, I guess you need to change your .joins statement to .joins(:retailer => :profile) I mean, :retailer is duplicated.